# getting js error "expected identifier" while using internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code for export PDF, it is working fine for all browsers but when I use it in IE it gives me a JS error like `expected identifier` for this line `$.fn.yiiGridView.export();`.

Can anyone please tell me how I can resolve this issue.

```
$('#export-button').on('click', function() {       
    $.fn.yiiGridView.export();
});
```

Comment: Please show the entire error.

Comment: What version(s) of IE?

Comment: @mevius  it shows error only expected identifier, thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` is a [reserved word in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords), so use the bracket notation instead:

```
$('#export-button').on('click', function() {       
    $.fn.yiiGridView['export']();
});
```

If you have created that function yourself, then it is better to use a different name, like `myexport`:

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.myexport = function () { .... };
```

and then:

```
$('#export-button').on('click', function() {       
    $.fn.yiiGridView.myexport();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now can you please tell me how can i call this function, i did code like $.fn.yiiGridView.export = function() { }; so it is giving me error, now how can i call the function like your given code ?

Comment: It is like I put in my question. You call the function that way. Notice the parentheses after `['export']`? That makes the call. It is just a different syntax for exactly the same thing.

Comment: I tried to call it like $.fn.yiiGridView['export'] = function() { }  this way but it is giving me error

Comment: That is not calling it. You are assigning a value to something that is a function! That is not what you want. Look at the code in the question: you *call* the function. So why do you now assign another empty function to it?

Comment: I wants to call this function, how can i call this function ?

Comment: Right now i use it like this $.fn.yiiGridView.export = function() { } but it is giving me same error expected identifier

Comment: That is *not* what you put in the question. Why do you do something different than you asked in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112797/discussion-between-nikul-and-trincot).